# How to add localStorage for color switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

The below example is working good in my website. I want to save the color switcher action using localStorage.

**Note : Problem not with the script. I need changing color theme will stay same color after the reload the page also.**

I don't know how to achieve it. Anyone help to resolve.

Thanks in advance.

[Reference color theme link](http://wahabali.com/work/pearl-demo/index-hotel.html#)

```js
$('#color-wrapper ul li, #color-wrapper p').click(function(){
  var color_scheme = $(this).attr('data-path');
  $('#color-switcher').attr('href',color_scheme);
});
```

```css
#color-wrapper { width: 180px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 5px; }
#color-wrapper h2 { margin: 5px 0 5px; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; color: #000; }
#color-wrapper ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#color-wrapper ul li { float: left; width: 26px; height: 26px; margin: 5px 10px 5px 0px;cursor: pointer;list-style: none; }
#color-wrapper ul li.thunder { background: #3a3138; }
#color-wrapper ul li.green { background: #2ecc71; }
#color-wrapper p { font-size: 14px; padding-top: 10px; color: #999; cursor: pointer; clear: both;}
#color-wrapper p:hover { color: #000; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1qauyj5k7w3asn/default.css?dl=0" id="color-switcher">

<div id="demo-colors" class="demo-colors">
     <div id="color-wrapper">          
          <h2>COLORS:</h2>          
          <ul>
              <li class="thunder" data-path="https://www.dropbox.com/s/stf3xvmxqm738lj/thunder.css?dl=0"></li>
              <li class="green" data-path="https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1qauyj5k7w3asn/default.css?dl=0"></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="clear"></div>   
          <p data-path="https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1qauyj5k7w3asn/default.css?dl=0">Restore Default</p>

     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the [documentation for localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) should allow you to write some code that actually uses localStorage

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you need to achieve? What do you mean by **' color switcher action'**?

Comment: http://wahabali.com/work/pearl-demo/index-hotel.html#. you check this sample website right side changing color theme of website. Like this type I want

Comment: Question not clear!!! not understandable. Please describe the actual problem you are facing, and please let us know what your code snippet is doing, I debug this code snippet and its not working !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first set the color scheme to a localStorage item

```
$('#color-wrapper ul li, #color-wrapper p').click(function(){
   var color_scheme = $(this).attr('data-path');
   $('#color-switcher').attr('href',color_scheme);
   localStorage.setItem('color_scheme', color_scheme);
});
```

when the page loads check if an item was previously saved and if so get the localStorage item and update the href

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var saved_color_scheme = localStorage.getItem('color_scheme');
    if(saved_color_scheme) {
       $('#color-switcher').attr('href', saved_color_scheme);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You only use `localStorage.setItem('color', 'value-in-string');`

```
$('#color-wrapper ul li, #color-wrapper p').click(function(){
  var color_scheme = $(this).attr('data-path');
  localStorage.setItem('color_scheme', color_scheme);
  $('#color-switcher').attr('href',color_scheme);
});
```

and when you need the color you get from localStorage `localStorage.getItem('color_scheme')`

Comment: you also need to write a function to get the value from localstorage and change the stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

you can add the style file dynamically and for this you can append the file into the head tag

```
$('#color-wrapper ul li, #color-wrapper p').click(function(){
    var color_scheme = $(this).attr('data-path');
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + color_scheme + '" type="text/css" />')
  $('#color-switcher').attr('href',color_scheme);
});
```

Comment: problem not with the script. I need the changing color theme will stay after the reload the page also.

Answer (score 0):

first you save on localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('color_scheme', color_scheme);
```

and on function *ready* with jquery you get the value (if doesn't exist will return null)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('color_scheme'))
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + color_scheme + '" type="text/css" />')
});
```